# Name that quote!

Tags: rebus, movies

Here is a fairly easy [rebus](/questions/tagged/rebus) for you, a quote from a movie:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's gotta be

> [Nobody puts Baby in a corner](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092890/quotes)

Comment: Glad to see that I'm not the only one who has seen that :D

Comment: Actually... I'm a little embarrassed to admit this: I'm only familiar with the quote because of _[Veronica Mars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nobody_Puts_Baby_in_a_Corner)_.

Comment: Awww man. (I'll accept your answer once the 15 minutes are up, due to your lightning speed answering).